# How to get the first value on a group by query in mysql?

Tags: mysql

i have a mysql table with id, llaveord, nomb, imp.

records come in pairs with the same llaveord, like :

| id | llaveord | nomb | imp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaaaa | some1 | 100 |
| 2 | aaaaa | xxx | 50 |
| 3 | bbbbb | some2 | 110 |
| 4 | bbbbb | xxx | 50 |
| 5 | ccccc | some3 | 70 |
| 6 | ccccc | xxx | 50 |

and i need to get this:

| llaveord | nomb | sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaaaa | some1 | 150 |
| bbbbb | some2 | 160 |
| ccccc | some3 | 120 |

but a regular group  by query shows this:

| llaveord | nomb | sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaaaa | xxx | 150 |
| bbbbb | xxx | 160 |
| ccccc | xxx | 120 |

Any idea how to get the first nomb instead of last?

TIA

Comment: Use window functions: One to get `SUM(imp)` the other gets the first `nomb`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use windowing functions here to obtain the desired results. Adjust the ordering criteria for `rn` as appropriate, assuming here "first" means the row with the lower Id.

```
select llaveord, nomb, sum 
from (
  select *, 
    Sum(imp) over(partition by llaveord) sum, 
    Row_Number() over (partition by llaveord order by Id) rn 
  from t
)t
where rn = 1;
```

Example [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1QkjzO6u)

Comment: I guess it is a perfect answer. However, I'd add a "classic" option without a window function. 
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g1g7dJeimCVwKNXofVtMPu/0

Comment: @artoodetoo, After October 2023, all supported versions of MySQL support window functions. If one is still using MySQL 5.x, it's a security risk.

Comment: Thank you for your information, Bill. Unortunately we live in imperfect world. :)